# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS sgirok-cli fails to start shared library problem?

Tags: command-line, apt, shared-library

`sudo apt update` && `sudo apt upgrade` run without errors.
`sudo apt install sigrok-cli` runs with No error messages and installs sigrok-cli into /usr/bin.

But on running `sigrok-cli` it immediately aborts with an error message

> sigrok-cli: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ldd /usr/bin/sigrok-cli returns nothing

The sigrok-cli is installed in /usr/bin

strings /usr/bin/sigrok-cli|grep nettle reports nothing

There is no libnettle.so.7 according to
dpkg -S libnettle.so.7
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *libnettle.so.7*

My system does have libnettle8
dpkg -S libnettle.so.8
libnettle8:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8.4
libnettle8:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8

if I search the entire root fs I find the following references to libnettle.so.7*

/snap/core20/1828/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7
/snap/core20/1828/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7.0
/snap/core20/1828/usr/share/doc/libnettle7
/snap/core20/1852/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7
/snap/core20/1852/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7.0
/snap/core20/1852/usr/share/doc/libnettle7
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7.0

What's going?  System seems stable, its largely used for C and embedded C and assembler programming gnu-gcc for arm, esp32 and avr, sdcc stmflash for 8 and 32 bit usbtiny and arduino

Comment: I would say it is very clear it does have dependencies. Do you have that file anywhere in your file system?

Comment: Please show us `which sigrok-cli`

Comment: AFAIK the version of nettle on 22.04 is libnettle8 not libnettle7

Comment: `sudo sigrok-cli --list-serial
[sudo] Passwort für alex: 
Available serial/HID/BT/BLE ports:
  /dev/ttyS4    ttyS4 snip` No prob here on jammy.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Perhaps `sigrok-cli` calls another program which has the dependency. Find out with `strings /usr/bin/sigrok-cli | less`

Comment: To see which package (if any) provides the `libnettle.so.7` file, use `dpkg -S libnettle.so.7`.